# How to generate a PDF using wicked_pdf from an API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wicked-pdf

Im creating an API that should generate a PDF based on some information on the database.

When trying to call the action im getting an error:

```
ActionController::UnknownFormat (ActionController::UnknownFormat):
app/controllers/v1/trips_controller.rb:56:in `print_monthly_trips'
```

This is my controllers:

```
/#application_controller.rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::API
  include Response
  include ExceptionHandler
  include Pundit
  include ActionController::MimeResponds

 /#trips_controler.rb
def print_monthly_trips

  @trips_to_print = current_user.trips_for_month(3)

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.pdf do
      render pdf: "file_name",
      template: "trips/report.html.erb",
      layout: 'pdf.html'
    end
    format.json do
      render pdf: "file_name",
      template: "trips/report.html.erb",
      layout: 'pdf.html'
    end
  end
end
```

My routes:

```
get 'print_monthly_trips', to: 'trips#print_monthly_trips'
```

Im calling my API with:

```
http GET https://localhost/print_monthly_trips Accept:'application/vnd.trips.v1+json' Authorization:'my_token'
```

So, why im getting this:

ActionController::UnknownFormat (ActionController::UnknownFormat):

app/controllers/v1/trips_controller.rb:56:in `print_monthly_trips'

Comment: what line is line 56?

Comment: respond_to do |format|

Comment: rails version? Is the pdf data type registered in `Mime::Type`? Why are you requesting `json` and returning a PDF? Your layout looks wrong according to the docs

Comment: Its just a test. My Mime types are like this:

Mime::Type.register "application/pdf", :pdf

Comment: Even if I only put this: 

      respond_to do |format|
        format.xml { render(xml: "fdsfds") }
        format.json { render(json: "fdsfdsfd" ) }
      end

It breaks the same way

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Rails controllers that inherit from `ActionController::API` don't have the ability to `render` views or use view helpers, which is necessary for many `WickedPdf` use-cases.

You can either move the PDF creating action to another non-API Rails controller that inherits from `ActionController::Base` instead, or instantiate one in your action like this:

```
def print_monthly_trips
  pdf_html = ActionController::Base.new.render_to_string(template: 'trips/report.html.erb', layout: 'pdf.html')
  pdf = WickedPdf.new.pdf_from_string(pdf_html)
  send_data pdf, filename: 'file_name.pdf'
end
```

If you don't want to incur the overhead to instantiate `ActionController::Base` just to generate a PDF, you may need to make some adjustments to your template, and build the HTML directly with ERB or Erubis something like this:

```
def print_monthly_trips
  layout = Erubis::Eruby.new(File.read(Rails.root.join('app/views/layouts/pdf.html.erb')))
  body = Erubis::Eruby.new(File.read(Rails.root.join('app/views/trips/report.html.erb')))
  body_html = body.result(binding)
  pdf_html = layout.result(body: body_html) # replace `yield` in layout with `body`
  pdf = WickedPdf.new.pdf_from_string(pdf_html)
  send_data pdf, filename: 'file_name.pdf'
end
```

But be aware you won't have access to view helpers, and most `wicked_pdf_asset` helpers this way.